# How to send signal from subprocess to parent process?

Tags: python

I tried using `os.kill` but it does not seem to be working.

```
import signal
import os
from time import sleep


def isr(signum, frame):
    print "Hey, I'm the ISR!"

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, isr)

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    def sisr(signum, frame):        
        os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGALRM)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGVTALRM, sisr)
    signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_VIRTUAL, 1, 1)

    while True:
        print "2"
else:
    sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `sisr` handler never executes.

```
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_VIRTUAL, 1, 1)
```

This line sets a virtual timer, which, according to documentation, *“Decrements interval timer **only when the process is executing**, and delivers SIGVTALRM upon expiration”*.

The thing is, your process is almost never executing. The prints take almost no time inside your process, all the work is done by the kernel delivering the output to your console application (xterm, konsole, …) and the application repainting the screen. Meanwhile, your child process is asleep, and the timer does not run.

Change it with a real timer, it works :)

```
import signal
import os
from time import sleep


def isr(signum, frame):
    print "Hey, I'm the ISR!"

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, isr)

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    def sisr(signum, frame):        
        print "Child running sisr"
        os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGALRM)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, sisr)
    signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 1, 1)

    while True:
        print "2"
        sleep(1)
else:
    sleep(10)
    print "Parent quitting"
```

Output:

```
spectras@etherbee:~/temp$ python test.py
2
Child running sisr    
2
Hey, I'm the ISR!
Parent quitting
spectras@etherbee:~/temp$ Child running sisr

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    sleep(1)
  File "test.py", line 15, in sisr
    os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGALRM)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

**Note:** the child crashes the *second* time it runs `sisr`, because then the parent has exited, so `os.getppid()` return `0` and sending a signal to process 0 is forbidden.

Comment: I did not know that "print" did not consume CPU time at all! Instead of printing I put in some arithmetic now. But thanks alot!

Comment: It does, but the amount it uses is negligible before the amount of time spent passing the text through the kernel to the console emulator, which then has to render the font onto the window, in turn instructing the window manager to send the refresh to the video driver, or whatever it does with it.

Comment: So when the timer operates (virtual), whatever happens in the kernel is not taken into account is it?